# What does SHA256 hexadecimal string look like?

Tags: sha256

I have been looking all over google to find what the hex output of a SHA256 hash looks like. But I just can't seem to find it.

So what does a SHA256 hash look like when it's converted to hexadecimal?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A SHA256 hash represented in hexadecimal consists of 64 hexadecimal characters, i.e. it matches the following regex:

```
^[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}$
```

*Example:*

```
7f83b1657ff1fc53b92dc18148a1d65dfc2d4b1fa3d677284addd200126d9069
```

Comment: In .NET it may also contain hyphens between the bytes. See http://dotnetfiddle.net/qrZsni

Comment: Note that the above regex will also match longer strings which happen to contain a sha256 hexadecimal hash. ^[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}$ will strictly match

Comment: `\b[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}\b` if you need to match a sha256 "word" within a text

Comment: Turn off case sensitivity with `i` and you don't have to do "A-Fa-f" e.g. `/^[0-9a-f]{64}$/i`