# What is a JS regex to match a sha256 word hash within a text?

Tags: javascript, regex, hash, sha256

On the following text

```
MD5 ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c
SHA1 2ef7bde608ce5404e97d5f042f95f89f1c232871
SHA256 7f83b1657ff1fc53b92dc18148a1d65dfc2d4b1fa3d677284addd200126d9069 
ssdeep3:aBn:aB 
File size 12 bytes ( 12 bytes ) 
File type Text 
Magic literal ASCII text, with no line terminators 
TrID    Unknown!
```

I want to match the hash the SHA256 value in JS:

```
7f83b1657ff1fc53b92dc18148a1d65dfc2d4b1fa3d677284addd200126d9069
```

Comment: @NicolasMaltais thanks for the comment. I mentioned this question on a comment on my answer below. Although related, both are asking two different things.

Comment: I actually created this question just to document the specific case for matching a SHA256 word in JS. Please note the mentioned question wants to know how it looks like, not the regex.

Comment: No offence, but the regex needed to match that is rather basic, I don't see the need to "document" it. Enforcing this further since it also is a duplicate.

Comment: The mentioned question is not about regex or js; although not agreeing, I understand why some may think it's a duplication. Please do not delete this QA, since some users may not think it's basic and benefit from this effort. Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

The following regex works for me:

```regex
\b[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}\b
```

Check the explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/AXhQLz/1

Comment: Related [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630168/what-does-sha256-hexadecimal-string-look-like/)