# how to calculate HASH256 on just a part of xml in JMETER

Tags: xml, hash, jmeter, hashcode

- I'm doing API testing using Jmeter3.1. [im junior tester and new]
- I have a test where i have to send an xml in request iteratively.
  with each iteration a different xml block is added in original xml.
  This xml block will be further evaluated by the recieving system and values will be stored in DB. This will be stored in form of Hash-256 in db tables.
  Now i need to :

[A] -  first calculate the Hash256 for this block of xml for each request.[*see yellow highlighted part in image]

[B]-   then secondly compare it after logging into the DB using jdbc sampler. [for this part i will get a query from developers.]
But i dont understand how to calculate the hash-256 for just the block of xml code and not the complete xml.
please see example below-
[in the image- the yellow background xml block i need to convert to hash-256 and then compare with db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsxMo.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><r:Document SchemaVersion="1.0" xmlns:r="http://www.qqq.ddqn.qqqv.qe/XSD/qq9/qqSchema" Status="000">
<r:DateTime>2020-09-02T09:28:15</r:DateTime>    <r:FileInfo Language="nl"><r:cSecurityNumbers><r:Legal Type="200" Structure="A1">
            <r:Date><r:Century>20</r:Century>
                <r:Year>20</r:Year>
                <r:Month>09</r:Month>
                <r:Day>21</r:Day>
            </r:Date>
            <r:Legal>06999996</r:Legal></r:Legal><r:Legal Type="200" Structure="A1">
            <r:Date>
                <r:Century>20</r:Century>
                <r:Year>20</r:Year>
                <r:Month>12</r:Month>
                <r:Day>1</r:Day>
            </r:Date>
            <r:Legal>06999996</r:Legal></r:Legal><r:Legal Type="200" Structure="A1">
            <r:Date>
                <r:Century>20</r:Century>
                <r:Year>20</r:Year>
                <r:Month>11</r:Month>
                <r:Day>3</r:Day>
            </r:Date>
            <r:Legal>06999996</r:Legal></r:Legal></r:cSecurityNumbers></r:FileInfo Language="nl"></r:Document>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know what is `HASH256`
2. As far as I can see your XML is malformed, this bit: `</r:FileInfo Language="nl">` should look like `</r:FileInfo>`

In any case you should be looking at [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language so you would be able to:

- Parse previous sampler response
- Fetch first `<Legal>` tag value
- Calculate [SHA256 Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630168/what-does-sha256-hexadecimal-string-look-like) out of it

Example code:

```
def data = new groovy.xml.XmlSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
def firstLegal = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bindNode(data.FileInfo.cSecurityNumbers.'*'[0]) as String
def hash256 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(firstLegal)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Processing XML](https://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [StreamingMarkupBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/xml/StreamingMarkupBuilder.html)
- [DigestUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html)

I cannot guarantee the above code will work as you expect due to the aforementioned 2 points, but it should guide you to the proper direction

Comment: 1. I have to use REQUEST  not RESPONSE.

Comment: 1. I have to use REQUEST  not RESPONSE.  your solution is for response!                                                                          2. I checked with developer over the xml point you mentioned he says its ok and its in use for 10 years now.  3 for hash 256 conversionyou can see this article- https://www.programmersought.com/article/67175301675/

Comment: If you have to use REQUEST than change `prev.getResponseDataAsString()` to `sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()`. If your DEVELOPER considers this XML as VALID then GOOD LUCK to both of YOU. The article YOU referenced doesn't contain ANY information about HASH256.

Comment: 1. i will try this.     2. i raised a bug for xml.      3. these two links may be usefull -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=netcore-3.1              and          https://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator

Comment: Its not working as expected. I have tried the code "sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()". Im getting exactly same hash as in your image. But your image is for Response. it is not the same when i paste the xml block in online converter. <r:Legal Type="200" Structure="A1"> <r:Date> <r:Century>20</r:Century> <r:Year>20</r:Year> <r:Month>09</r:Month> <r:Day>21</r:Day> </r:Date> <r:Legal>06999996</r:Legal> </r:Legal> HEX: B8A575A3E198437B54EFEBB626BC69BA241C0F865EFD612C3AABC1B0BBCC9411 hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator